Sorting selected items in ng-select2-component
I have a project in Angular 15 that uses the ng-select2-component npm library for the dropdown component (both single and multi). The selected dropdown values themselves are attached to a form group within a form array.
My requirement at the moment is to somehow make the selected values sortable through drag and drop whilst also updating the order in the form.
I found some JQuery solutions in here but all of them on the old select2 component, not the Angular specific one. None of them worked so far.
Any suggestions?

Sorting selected is added in 17.1.0.
See : https://github.com/Harvest-Dev/ng-select2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#v1710-2024-12-26

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
